# Scrambled 'slugs' config when saving a Sylius product form

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, slug, sylius

When saving a Product via the Sylius product form I am getting the following error:
Notice: Undefined index: slugs in vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Sluggable/SluggableListener.php line 181

Somehow the indexs have been scrambled and looks like this:

```
 array('�4E\E' => array('slug' => array('array_' => array('name'), '�NE\' => 'slug', '�,\E' => 'default', '' => '-', 'ations/val' => 'Y-m-d-H:i', 'liip_i' => true, '�PE' => null, 'demo5/' => '', '1\E' => '', 'ndor/syl' => array())), '�}G\E' => 'ProductBundle\Entity\Product'))
```

I'm extending the product form and model but I haven't touched the product name or how gedmo works

I'm running "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "v2.3.7" and "sylius/sylius": "v0.9.0"

I've been able to load the data fixtures ok

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Hi, have you sorted it out? I have the same error.

Comment: Yes I've sorted it but I'm not sure what was the cause. I cleared the Symfony cache and the php apc cache. See if that helps.